# Transforming data frame into a range label in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
df <- data.frame(Var1=c(1:10))

   Var1
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10
```

I want to transform the data frame above into a range label like for example: "1 and below","1 to 2", "3 to 4" and so on until "10 and above". So I created this loop below:

```
rangelist <- function(i){
  start=paste( df$Var1[1],"and below")
  middle=paste( df$Var1[i+1],"to", df$Var1[i+2])
  last=paste(df$Var1[nrow(df)],"and above") 


  paste(start)
  paste(middle)
  paste(last)

}



sapply(1:nrow(df),rangelist)
```

But the loop above return me this:

```
[1] "10 and above" "10 and above" "10 and above" "10 and above" "10 and above" "10 and above"
 [7] "10 and above" "10 and above" "10 and above" "10 and above"
```

Comment: Instead of this, I suggest you look at the `cut` function.

Comment: "1 and below" and "1 to 2" ranges overlap? Or they are "Below 1" and "1 to 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
indx <- df$Var1[-c(1, nrow(df))]
df$label <-  c('1 and below', paste(indx-1, indx, sep=' to '), '10 and above')
df$label
 #[1] "1 and below"  "1 to 2"       "2 to 3"       "3 to 4"       "4 to 5"      
 #[6] "5 to 6"       "6 to 7"       "7 to 8"       "8 to 9"       "10 and above"
```

#### Update

A bit more general would be

```
 indx <- setdiff(1:nrow(df), c(1, nrow(df)))
 with(df, c(paste(Var1[1], 'and below'), sprintf('%s to %s', Var1[indx-1],
              Var1[indx]), paste(Var1[nrow(df)], 'and above')))
 #[1] "1 and below"  "1 to 2"       "2 to 3"       "3 to 4"       "4 to 5"      
 #[6] "5 to 6"       "6 to 7"       "7 to 8"       "8 to 9"       "10 and above"
```